# React Router v4 - Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am a beginner for React. I just need to get the path param from the URL when the page is loaded. My URL is as follows.

```
http://localhost:3000/explorer/test/111
```

I have set the route like following,

```
<Route
    exact path="/explorer/test/:id"
    component={() => <BlockPage />}
  />
```

Then in the `<BlockPage />` component I need to get the value of `:id` when the component is loading. Therefore, I added the following code segment to get an id, but it gives me error as in the title.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavigationComp from './Navigation';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const BlockPage = () =>
   <div>
      <NavigationComp/>
      <BlockData />
   </div>

class BlockData extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
       console.log(this.props.match.params.id);
    }

    render(){
        return(.....)
    }
}

export default withRouter(BlockPage);
```

What is the mistake I did? Can someone explain to me? my objective is to get 111 value from URL into `componentDidMount()`

Answer (score 1):

when you want to use component you dont need function like you code you can change it like it :

```
<Route
exact path="/explorer/test/:id"
component={<BlockPage />}
/>
```

or use render function if you want a function  like this

```
 <Route
exact path="/explorer/test/:id"
render={(props) => <BlockPage {...props} />}
/>
```

then in `this.props.match.params` you can access your id.

Comment: Can you please explain me this. I change the Route like in the second method which you mentioned, but it remains the same error for me. (TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined)

Comment: How can I access the :id in the componentDidMount() ?

Comment: @SajithaLiyanage are you use `render` function that I say ?

Comment: @SajithaLiyanage my next question is if you `console.log(this.props)` what you see in console? please wirte this line int `BlockPage componentDidMount`

Comment: @SajithaLiyanage what if you remove `withRouter` and just export the component

Comment: I tried both cases, In console.log(this.props) gives the empty object.

Comment: I found the issue. The issue is in here.                                        
 `const BlockPage = () =>
   <div>
      <NavigationComp/>
      <BlockData />
   </div> `

Router connect with component `BlockPage` . But my componentDidMount function is in the `BlockData` component. I think it needs to pass props from `BlockPage` to `BlockData`. Can you explain me how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you the component is sub component of other component which ReactRouter knows. For example,

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/Feedback">
        <Switch>
<BrowserRouter>
```

in the above route defnition, the match object in Feedback component is not null, but if we have other component in feedback and tries to access it it's an error.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57628327/12378703
this works perfectly... try this out

```
<Route
exact path="/explorer/test/:id"
render={(props) => <BlockPage {...props} />}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
<CPAroute exact path="/advcampaigns/:id" component={AdvCampaigns}/>
```

```
class AdvCampaigns extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            activePage: 1
        };
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.**computedMatch**.params.id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem.
Tried all the above solutions, but didn't work.
Then I just console logged `this.props`

```
const productName = this.props.params.<YOUR_DYNAMIC_URL>;
```

***WITHOUT match in this.props***

And it worked, don't know how but it worked.
May be helpful for others.